# How to map over json and set the key name to a variable with a matching string

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following returned json (with what I think are key value pairs) from the `event.body` from this function `exports.handler =  async (event, context, callback) => {`

```
{"name":"Anders","package":"Silver","email":"email@email.com","subject":"fdsafa","weightLoss":"false","strength":"on","message":"test"}
```

I am wondering how to iterate over it and check when any of the values is false, and if it is false change the value to name of the key?

So something like this in psuedo code

map over event.body, and check if any of the key's values are equal to false if so create a variable with the name of the key and the value of the key's name as a string.

So in this example json one variable called `weightLoss` would be created `var weightLoss = "weightLoss"`

Update with some more code of what I am trying to do

```
exports.handler =  async (event, context, callback) => {

    const payload = JSON.parse(event.body)

    const body1 = event.body;

    Object.entries(body1).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value === 'false') {
        body1[key] = key;
    }
    });

    console.log(body1);

    const { email, subject } = payload

    ...
```

So this is all testing if a value is checked or not in a form. So the outputs I get from the console depending on if it's checked or not are these.

checked

```
{"name":"Anders","package":"Silver","email":"email@email.com","subject":"fdsafa","weightLoss":"on","strength":false,"message":"fdsasfdsdafsdafasdfasd"}
```

unchecked

```
{"name":"Anders","package":"Silver","email":"email@email.com","subject":"fdsafa","weightLoss":false,"strength":false,"message":"fdsasfdsdafsdafasdfasd"}
```

Comment: where are you going to use this magic "variable" later on?

Comment: why isn't adding all of the "false" to array an option? ["weightLoss"] in your sample

Comment: I guess adding to an array would be good as well. I just have a bunch of values from a form checkbox that I need to send to sendgrid's template engine and sending the value false wouldn't help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const body = {"name":"Anders","package":"Silver","email":"email@email.com","subject":"fdsafa","weightLoss":"false","strength":"on","message":"test"};

Object.entries(body).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value === 'false') {
    body[key] = key;
  }
});

console.log(body);
```

Comment: I tried making the variable body equal to event.body where the json is. And The values are still outputting either on or false? I will post more code to explain

Comment: I added what I tried with your code and I am still stuck, hopefully you can help.

Comment: @AndersKitson Instead of `const body1 = event.body` use `const body1 = payload`. Because `event.body` is a string. It will be much easier to use directly `payload` instead of creating the new variable `body1`.

Comment: hmm, I still get the same problem but now it's formatted better in my console, but still not changing the payload values for false items, still just says on or false.

Comment: @AndersKitson Looking at the updates it seems that the value is a boolean (`false`) not a string (`"false"`). To make it work, use `if (value === false)` instead of `if (value === "false")` (no quotes).

Comment: Kewl that's exactly what I need, I have a a couple more steps to really format it correctly for sendgrid, but I will post that as a separate question.